# Console logging quicksort cuts sorting

Tags: javascript, quicksort, console.log

I was just running through some practice problems to refresh on sorting and I came across this issue?

I'm quicksorting an array and when I `console.log(quicksort(inputArray).toString());` it doesn't finish the remaining number.

Here's a JSFiddle of the code https://jsfiddle.net/qLyt1yfv/

```js
function quicksort(inputArray) {
  if (inputArray.length <= 1) {
    return inputArray;
  } else {

    var left_subarray = [];
    var right_subarray = [];
    var newArray = [];
    var pivot = inputArray.pop();
    var length = inputArray.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (inputArray[i] <= pivot) {
        left_subarray.push(inputArray[i]);
      } else {
        right_subarray.push(inputArray[i]);
      }
    }

    return newArray.concat(quicksort(left_subarray), pivot, quicksort(right_subarray));
  }
}

var input = [51, 42, 96, 83, 37, 5, 24];
var resultArray = quicksort(input);

console.log(quicksort(input).toString());
console.log("Result Array: " + resultArray);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = resultArray.toString();
```

```html
<h1 id="result">Quicksort: </h1>
```

Comment: I copied your code from JSFiddle into a SO code snippet.  It's considered best practice to not be dependant on external links, in case they go away. It's also easier for users, so you're more likely to get results.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the following:

```
var pivot = inputArray.pop();
```

You're modifying the original array by deleting its last element.

You can solve this by either doing a copy of the original array before doing the sort, or by pushing the element back to the array before returning the results:

```
inputArray.push(pivot);
```

Comment: But doesn't the if statement catch that before I pop? And I don't understand why it only cuts off in console log?

Comment: Kinda, but it is only pushing it back to the other array `left_subarray`, and not the original `inputArray`. It cut off in the console log because the first time you called `quicksort`, it modified the original array, and then you called it again but this time printed the results in the console, hence missing one element. You can check that by putting `console.log("test: " + input);` after the first call to `quicksort`, then you'll see that your function always removes the last element from the original input.

Comment: Ohhh! Haha I see it now, sorry for the dumb question, I'll delete this.

Answer (score 0):

You pass inputArray into quicksort function and remove a element of it by inputArray.pop()

You should not pass input array, just pass copy of this array